# How to increase-decrease the number (i.e. 0, 1,4..) size in CSS?

Tags: html, css

In my website, a paragrap (which sits inside the header)is made up of number (i.e. telephone number) and some text (i.e. email adderss). Now I have enclosed then in one same paragraph, set their font-size: small. But the problem is in my browser, the number looks a few size bigger than the text (which is email address in my case). Why so? How can I make them look as same size as the text(may be decreasing the size of number?)? This is how it looks like right now:

[image]

.HTML:

```
<div id="header_area">

                <h1>


                    7seas Redovisning
                            <p id="contact_address_header">
                        Mob: 076-000000<br /> Tel: 000000<br />
                            info@7abcdefgh.se

                            </p>
                </h1>

        </div>
```

.CSS:

```
#header_area{
    background-image: url('img_ain/7seas.jpeg'), 

                     url('img_ain/7seas.jpeg');

    background-repeat: no-repeat, 

                       no-repeat;

    background-position: 220px top;
    margin-top:10px;

    }
h1{
    text-align:center;
    /*
    margin-top:55px;
    */

    color:green;

    border-bottom:2px solid Crimson ;


    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px yellow;

    padding-bottom:40px;
    padding-top:45px;
    font-family:Prisoner SF;

}


    #contact_address_header{

    float:right;
    margin-right:40px;
    margin-top:-15px;
    color:#6495ED;
    font-size: small;
    font-family:Euphemia;

    }
```

Comment: Thats the same font size. Choose a different font where numbers' heights are closely matched to that of alphabets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the font-size is the same for both the numbers and the alphabets but if you'd still like to reduce the font-size of the numbers, you can wrap your numbers with a `<span></span>` tag like this:

```
            <h1>


                7seas Redovisning
                        <p id="contact_address_header">
                    Mob: <span class="numbers">076-000000</span><br /> Tel: <span class="numbers">000000</span><br />
                        info@7abcdefgh.se

                        </p>
            </h1>
```

And then set a different font-size for the `span` tag like this:

```
#contact_address_header{
    font-size: small;
}
.numbers {
    font-size: 10px; 
}
```

By the way, I don't know your requirements but using the `<p>` tag inside the `<h1>` tag **isn't valid** HTML.

---

```css
#contact_address_header {
  font-size: small;
}
.numbers {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
                7seas Redovisning
                        <p id="contact_address_header">
                    Mob: <span class="numbers">076-000000</span><br /> Tel: <span class="numbers">000000</span><br />                     info@7abcdefgh.se

                        </p>
            </h1>
```

Comment: Fahad Hasan, I am sure that your suggestion will help. However, there was no specific requirement. I am a new designer. May be all I am doing isn't the way as it should be. Can you help me to improve the "header" section? I feel that it's not good to enclose another paragraph inside a header. Then please tell me how it could be done in the better way (by keeping the output same)?

Comment: @jabir_fatah Instead of using the `<p>` tag, you can use the `<span>` tag. Please check the HTML inside this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y6nknckx/6/.

Comment: @jabir_fatah You're welcome and I am glad to have helped you. Please mark my answer as correct so that users can know your query has been answered. Thank you.

Comment: @jabir_fatah, this is a correct answer to both questions that you asked. Please accept it. If you have other questions, ask them separately, not in comments. But note that code review issues are off-topic at SO.

Comment: i did it. but accepting answer requires a ceratin amount of time to ve overed, thats why i was late.